# Clipping glitch on models

Tags: modeling

I was following a tutorial on YouTube from Dikko on retopologying the face and when it had come to retopo the lips I wanted to turn off the *Object Properties< Viewport Display < In Front* on the reotopology and I couldn't see the model when facing it.

I guessed it was because I had another copy of the retopo face so I turned that off, but nothing happened.

While working on it I then thought "oh maybe it's the *view < Clip start* " Because I played around with that, Nothing. I tried importing the head sculpt to the project because I had separately sculpted the head in another blender project, the error is still being applied to the copy. So I guess I don't know what I'm doing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Viewport shading > Click the arrow > Disable Backface Culling

[image: Steps Image]

But if you are also exporting to game engine:
Select object > Go to edit mode > select everything (Press "A") > Go to Mesh (left top part of the viewport)> Normals > Recalculate outside

[image: Steps Image]
EDIT: Game Engines have the backface culling "locked on" thats why you need to rotate normals as shown above

Comment: Thank you,
Viewport shading > Click the arrow > Disable Backface Culling 

Thank you so much, It worked well!!!